# ASP.NET Core in Docker /app/Views/Email not found

Tags: image, docker, razor, asp.net-core

I have an ASP.NET Core and I am using template to sent email notification for user registration and reset password. Everything is working fine when I run the application on localhost, but when I build the image and run in a Linux Ubuntu Server I get the error `/app/Views/Email not found`

This is how I a getting the view:

```
var razorPage = GetRazorPage("Views/Email");

private RazorLightEngine GetRazorPage(string view)
{
    string currentDirectory = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
    var fullPath = Path.Combine(currentDirectory, view);
    return new RazorLightEngineBuilder().UseFilesystemProject(fullPath).UseMemoryCachingProvider().Build();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that the file was not available in Docker. I modify the file properties and it solved the issue.

[image]